# 'fltKernel.h' missing when trying to build driver Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, wdk

Can't build driver, Visual Studio 2012
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fltKernel.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\km**

to

**Additional Include Directories**

in **C/C++ / General**

Comment: Unfortunately, all of my Windows Kits folders, regardless of version, don't have the km folder.  Reproduced with 10240, 10586, 16299, 17134, 17763, 18362, 19041, and 20348.

Comment: @srbrills I think the point is to add the SDK folder and I assume if you add the parent folder of the “km” it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that's with the Windows 8 WDK? Just make sure that the header was installed in your kits header directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km"). Also note that fltKernel.h is a kernel mode header, so you can only include it in kernel mode driver projects.

If the header is missing from your installation, I'd recommend reinstalling the WDK. If it is not missing and it still isn't found for some reason, you could try manually adding its absolute path to your list of included headers to see if it fixes the issue. If that works (it should), then you can figure out why it was missing from your include path in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The file is part of the windows driver kit, likely you need to configure your build tool to use the correct windows SDK. (and also make sure you have go through your setup on Visual Stdio to add the SDK)